Next stable version of Mozilla Thunderbird
Where I can find out what will be next stable version of Mozilla Thunderbird? Current stable version is 115 and previous was 102. Is there a public roadmap for Mozilla Thunderbird to find out this?

https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

You can check out this link. Where they have all the major features that they will be working on next. They are just planned features/bug fixes for 2024 and there is no date assigned for it. You can read about that on the link provided.

I know this page. There is no any information on next major version of Thunderbird (version number, release date).
